# Magento - Display a custom text in product page, only for products from specific categories

Tags: php, magento

I need to show a text near the price for all products inside specific categories.

I've found this code that works, but it works only for one specific category.
I need to put 119, 120, 121, 122 etc... more categories id, not only one.

Can you help me?

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
            <?php if($category->getId()==119): ?>
            <span class="price-specification">
            <?php echo $this->__('Price per meter.'); ?><br />
            <?php echo $this->__('Sold only in multiples of three.'); ?>
            </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display text on more than 1 specific categories, simply do the following:

- Create an array of all category ids in which you want to show this text.
  For example: $arr = array(19, 120, 121, 122);
- Now in place of

  if($category->getId()==119):

put the following code:

```
if(in_array($category->getId(),$arr)):
```

Please let me know if you have any question.